# E: Package 'openresolv' has no installation candidate (Ubuntu 22.10)

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

So this is a pretty obvious error but I can't understand why.

I have run

`sudo apt update`

and then try to install using

`sudo apt -y install openresolv`

Which gives the error

```
Package openresolv is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'openresolv' has no installation candidate
```

I need this package to run the PureVPN client.

Answer (score 3):

Since Ubuntu Kinetic 22.10, the default implementation and I believe only implementation of resolv.conf and as such, both the `resolvconf` and `openresolv` implementations of `resolvconf` functionality were **removed** during the 22.10 development cycle.

Per [removal bug #1990743 on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1990743):

> systemd-resolved now implements the resolvconf interface, and Conflicts: with other implementations of resolvconf. Installing these other implementations on a full system or container will wrongly result in removal of the systemd-resolved package. We should drop resolvconf and openresolv now from the archive (and blacklist them).
> -- bug description

> Upon further inspection, it turns out that systemd-resolved now implements the resolvconf interface. We should drop resolvconf and openresolv now from the archive, and users requesting resolvconf will be directed to systemd-resolved. Packages which depend/recommend systemd-resolved will also get the supported implementation going forward.
>
> Using this bug for the removal of resolvconf and openresolv.
>
> --comments by Steve Langasek (vorlon), an archive admin and seasoned Ubuntu developer

If `openresolv` is required by PureVPN, you will need to talk to the PureVPN developers and have them **provide updated packages** because `systemd-resolved` is now the primary mechanism for resolvconf interfaces.  PureVPN developers will need to update their packaging in accordance with this change and removal.